# Scrolling wheel on non-apple mouse behaving weirdly

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse

EDIT: problem solved after updating my mac today

I had a problem with scrolling wheels with multiple mice. I'll try to describe it here:

Suppose I scroll in a given direction, at a given speed. Then almost always, and every few seconds, the page I'm scrolling "jumps" in the backward direction during a fraction of a second before I can continue scrolling in my wanted direction.

I captured a video of my screen that you can see in the this GIF: http://g.recordit.co/4m6OIVfQKf.gif. I'm scrolling down (i.e. I want to see the bottom contents of the page), but as you could see, every now and then, the scroll bar on the right goes in the opposite direction.

I have tried using tools that supposedly make scrolling with mice as smooth as scrolling with the trackpad (such as Mos and Smooze), but no success so far.

My mouse is not broken, and my finger didn't slip or something.

Do you have any recommendations ?

Thank you

Comment: The gif is a bit jumpy itself to really see what's happening, & it looks like you have smoothscroll off, which will make any mis-read of your mouse optics even jumpier.

Comment: The gif is jumpy because that is the real life speed ! I scrolled the wheel in the right direction but as slow as possible. The physical wheel is not continuous, it's like a discretization of 2pi = n * theta, and I was rolling one theta at a time !

Comment: Switching smooth scroll on might help. All mice these days have discrete moves; they're optical so they clock one 'window' at a time. They're usually detented so one tactile click = one optical window. Dust will upset them, a lot.

Comment: I installed a smooth scroll app after seeing your first comment, and while it did make the scroll continuous, it didn't solve the issue of random direction change. I'm still unsure whether it's a problem with mac and external mice, or a physical problem similar to what you mentioned (dust).

Comment: I've been using external mice for over 30 years - I absolutely loathe trackpads;) if it's jumpy it's likely to have fluff or a hair in the mechanism. Strip & clean time.

Comment: Are the multiple mice different brands?  Can you try them with a Windows machine? FWIW I just plugged in a $10 no-name USB mouse with a scroll wheel to my MBP 13 Catalina machine and I cannot reproduce your problem, the wheel works fine, consistently, at any speed. Could be a physical issue with your mouse.  Dirt, or a design flaw ... try a different brand.

Comment: Would you mind adding a picture of all the mice to your question?

Comment: The problem disappeared today after updating my Mac ! Thanks for your comments

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried disabling scroll acceleration with Linear Mouse, smooth scrolling with MOS, nothing helps. It keeps jumping in the opposite direction persistently.

Comment: Let’s close this. Your edit should be an answer and ideally, list which macOS update caused the fix so others can know what to do if they have a similar issue.